# Change the format of the time stamp in the post title in HUGO-Xmin theme

Tags: css, r, hugo, blogdown

I built a site with the R blogdown package:

```
install.packages('blogdown')
blogdown::new_site(theme='yihui/hugo-xmin')
blogdown::serve_site()
```

A post title in xmin theme looks like this:

[image]

I was wondering how to display the complete time stamp such as `2017-08-17 15:22:06 GMT` beneath the author instead of the date `2017/08/17`?

Comment: yihui/hugo-xmin, as I mentioned already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date is formatted on [this line](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/blob/c14ca049d0dd60386264ea68c91d8495809cc4c6/layouts/_default/single.html#L5) in the template `single.html` of the hugo-xmin theme:

```
{{ if .Params.date }}<h2 class="date">{{ .Date.Format "2006/01/02" }}</h2>{{ end }}
```

You can change the format `2006/01/02` to `2006-01-02 15:04:05 GMT`. See [the documentation of the `.Format` function](https://gohugo.io/functions/format/) for more information.